# pandas.DataFrame: aggregate rows based on regex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

### What I want to do

I have a trouble to clean my data because some values were not input correctly.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[1, 2], [2, 4], [3, 6], [4, 8], [5, 10]]
index = ['100: Test', '100: test', '101: FOO', '102: WWW', '101: foo foo']
columns = ['column1', 'column2']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=columns)

print(df)
## Current output!!!!
#              column1  column2
#100: Test           1        2
#100: test           2        4
#101: FOO            3        6
#102: WWW            4        8
#101: foo foo        5       10

## DO SOMETHING!!!!

print(df)
## Expected output!!!!
#           column1  column2
#100: Test        2        4
#101: FOO         8       16
#102: WWW         4        8
```

My `DataFrame.index` consists of "ID" + "Name". However, names are not correct, so one ID may show up in more than one row.

**Two requests**

- Sum up rows with the same ID.
- Choose one name for the result. (For example, I can use either "Test" or "test" for ID=100.)

### What I tried

I tried to use `groupby` function, but it doesn't seem to have `regex` compatibility.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

```
df2 = df.groupby(level=0).sum()
print(df2)
## Output
#              column1  column2
#100: Test           1        2
#100: test           2        4
#101: FOO            3        6
#101: foo foo        5       10
#102: WWW            4        8
```

### Environment

Python 3.10.5
Pandas 1.4.3

Answer (score 0):

Your expected output for `Test` does not reflect that you are trying to do a summation, but from what I can gather this is what you want. `groupby` can take a function or a mapping or even a series as the `by` argument. Here, you just want the lowercase version of the index:

```
df.groupby(df.index.str.lower()).sum()
```

which gives

```
           column1  column2
100: test        3        6
101: foo         8       16
102: www         4        8
```

Here, what I've done is passed it the lowercase index, and it simply groups the rows based on matching elements in the series.

### Edit

Based on the updated question, to match the numbers, you can use regular expressions:

```
df.groupby(df.index.str.extract(r"(\d+):", expand=False)).sum()
```

which gives

```
     column1  column2
100        3        6
101        8       16
102        4        8
```

It isn't clear what would take precedence `101: foo foo`  or `101: FOO`, it seems like the numbers here are the important part regardless.

Comment: Sorry, the question wasn't clear enough. It's not only about upper case or lower case. I updated the question for clarity. Old: "101: foo" --> New: "101: foo foo".

Comment: @dmjy See my edit

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Data Import
data = [[1, 2], [2, 4], [3, 6], [4, 8], [5, 10]]
index = ['100: Test', '100: test', '101: FOO', '102: WWW', '101: foo']
columns = ['column1', 'column2']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=columns)

# Data Pre-process
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.rename(columns={'index':'ID_Name'},inplace=True)
df['ID'] = df['ID_Name'].str.split(':').str[0]
df.sort_values(['ID','ID_Name'],inplace=True)
df_group = df.groupby(['ID'])[['column1','column2']].sum().reset_index()
df_group
df = pd.merge(df,df_group,how='left',left_on='ID',right_on='ID')
df_final = df.groupby(['ID']).first()

# Data Clean Process
df_final.rename(columns={'column1_y':'column1','column2_y':'column2'},inplace= True)
df_final.drop(['column1_x','column2_x'],axis = 1 , inplace=True)

# Output Display
df_final
```

Hi Dmjy,

I have attached the code for you, please try from your side,
and if you still have any question please let me know

Thanks
Leon